# Mac changes IP total length field

Tags: macos, sockets, ip, wireshark

I'm programming with sockets in Mac 10.6.8. Whenever I receive a packet, it starts with the IP header. I've been using Wireshark to analyze incoming packets, and I noticed that my machine's socket implementation will consistently change the "total length" field in the IP header. Specifically, it will subtract the IP header length and reverse the bytes (from network to host order).

For example, here's the beginning of an IP header as reported by Wireshark:

```
45 c0 00 38 ...
```

That breaks down as follows:

- 4 bits (0x4): IP version: 4
- 4 bits (0x5): IP header length: 5 words (20 bytes)
- 8 bits (0xc0): differentiated services flags
- 16 bits (0x0038): total length: 56 bytes

However, when I print the contents of the buffer filled by `recvfrom` for the same packet, I get a different lede:

```
ssize_t recvbytes = recvfrom(sock->fd, buffer, size, /*flags=*/0,
  (struct sockaddr*)src, &src_len);
```

returns

```
45 c0 24 00 ...
```

- 4 bits (0x4): IP version: 4
- 4 bits (0x5): IP header length: 5 words (20 bytes)
- 8 bits (0xc0): differentiated services flags
- 16 bits (0x2400): total length: 9216 bytes (?!)

I figured out that before I get access to the buffer, the socket implementation is reading the total length, subtracting the IP header length, and then writing it back in host order (little endian on my machine) rather than network order (big endian). In this example, that means:

- read the total length: 0x0038 = 56
- subtract the header length: 56 - 20 = 36
- write back in host order: 36 = 0x0024 (big endian) = 0x2400 (little endian = host order on my machine)

The problem gets worse. It won't just change the total length of the outermost IP header. It will also change the total length fields of internal IP headers, e.g., the one buried in an ICMP "time exceeded" message (which must include the original IP header of the dropped packet). Funnier still, it won't subtract the IP header length from the internal headers; it  just reverses the byte order.

Is this happening to anyone else? Is it part of a standard I'm unaware of? Is there a way to fix my machine's socket implementation to stop tampering with packets? How is Wireshark able to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

EDIT: My code and Makefile are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/netutils). I wrote a `fixip_osx` function to allow verifying IP checksums:

https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/netutils/blob/master/lib/ip.c

```
void fixip_osx(struct ip* ip) {
  /* Something on my Mac subtracts the header length from `ip_len` and stores
   * it in host order (little endian). */
  u16_t ip_hdrlen = ip->ip_hl << 2;
  u16_t ip_totlen = ip->ip_len + ip_hdrlen;
  ip->ip_len = htons(ip_totlen);
}
```

However, it's still a problem for verifying ICMP checksums when the payload contains another IP header.

The problem exists whether I compile with Clang 3.2 (built from trunk) or GCC 4.7 (MacPorts port), so I assume the problem lies in either the sockets implementation (packaged with Mac OS) or in Mac OS X itself.

Comment: "How is Wireshark able to get around this problem?"  It, like tcpdump, uses libpcap to capture raw networking packets, bypassing the IP protocol stack entirely (going through BPF on OS X and \*BSD, PF_PACKET sockets on Linux, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BSD suite of platforms (excluding OpenBSD) present the IP offset and length in host byte order.  All other platforms present in the received network byte order.  This is a "feature", and is referenced in the man page for [IP(4) - Internet Protocol](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/4/ip/) (FreeBSD, [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/ip.4.html)).

> The ip_len and ip_off fields must be provided in host byte order . 
>   All other fields must be provided in network byte order.

IP length can equal `packet length - IP header length` in FreeBSD/NetBSD.

Reference: *Stevens/Fenner/Rudolph, Unix Network Programming Vol.1, p.739*

I have to deal with these anomalies with a user space implementation of the PGM network protocol, specific code:

https://code.google.com/p/openpgm/source/browse/trunk/openpgm/pgm/packet_parse.c#76

It's actually quite annoying to detect for AutoConf, I think all packages have this hard coded on a per-platform basis.  I've seen a bug report ([header byte order config options detected incorrectly](https://code.google.com/p/openpgm/issues/detail?id=27)) raised this week on this very issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that Mac itself is doing that.  That would fundamentally break the IP protocol if it were.  More likely whatever is capturing the packets and delivering them to `recvfrom()` (presumably you are doing a promiscuous network capture, right?) is what is transforming the data after Mac is done processing it. ireshark operates on a lower level and has access to the actual network data.

Comment: The socket is not in a promiscuous capture mode.

Comment: How are you receiving an IP header from `recvfrom()`? Normally it would only give you a packet's payload, not its headers. Are you using a `RAW` socket to sniff network traffic?

Comment: I have put the code [on GitHub](https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/netutils/blob/master/lib/icmp.c). I'm using a SOCK_DGRAM with the IPPROTO_ICMP protocol. It gives me the IP header.